# High coupling using Doctrine\ORM relationships

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I was [studying the Doctrine\ORM library](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html), but in parallel, also studying object oriented design principles.

So I noticed that the relationships of entities in Doctrine\ORM are made by a direct reference to `Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection`, creating a high coupling between my entity and the library.

How to avoid that? There is another ways to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: I initialize the variables in my Entities with simple arrays and set the type of the getters and setters to iterable to prevent this. I also use yaml mapping instead of annotations to do not directly couple my entities to the ORM.